# Nifi Jolt transformation string to json array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Hi I have following Json input but as you can see "sites" is coming as string but it is actually array of strings which is escaped with \

'''
{
"name":"test",
"Id" : "123",
"sites": "["BR","DM","LM","MC","WK","ZZ"]"
}
'''

What I need to transform above using Nifi is as follow

'''
{
"name":"test",
"Id" : "123",
"sites": ["BR","DM","LM","MC","WK","ZZ"]
}
'''
how we can do this?

Comment: You have the same input and output...

Comment: Where did you get this "json" from, since it's not correctly formatted?
If you can't change from source side the way this json is build/encoded, you could use ReplaceText processors to remove the double quotes that are unwanted by using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two ReplaceText processors, like here:
[image]
[image]

The first one will replace text **"[** with **[** while the second one will replace **]"** with **]**